# How to make an HTML input show as asterisk "like a password input" except for the last 4 digits?

Tags: jquery, masking, maskedinput, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I have a form that allows a user to type in a social security number. I want the HTML input to hide the first 5 digits while only showing the last 4 digits.

For example, if the user types `123-45-6789`, then the input will show `***-**-6789`. I am using the [Inputmask Plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) to mask the input and force the user to type in the digits in the set format. However, I am puzzled with how to show the first 5 digits as asterisk while making the rest visible.

Here is the mask I am currently using

```
<input type="text" class="masked-input" data-inputmask="'mask': '999-99-9999'" value="" />
```

Here is how I activate that input

```
(function () {

    Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll(".masked-input"));
});
```

How to make input show as asterisk "password" except for the last 4 digits? If it is not possible using this plugin, how can I do it without this plugin or using other plugins?

Comment: If I've only typed 8 digits so far, should it display "****5678" or "*****678"?

Comment: @JohnWu The mask requires 9 digits. If you type 8 digits "and still typing" then the mask would show `***-**-678`

Answer (score 0):

Closest I could get is the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var new_value = '';
      $('body').on('keyup', '#maskInput', function(event){
        var curr_value = $(this).val();
        if (event.which == 8) {
          if(curr_value.length<1){
            new_value = '';
          }else{
            var omitted = curr_value.slice(0, -1);
            $(this).val(omitted);
          }
        }else{
          var ch = curr_value.charAt(curr_value.length-1);
          if(curr_value.length<8){
            if(ch == '-'){
              new_value = new_value+'-';
            }else{
              new_value = new_value+'*';
            }
            $(this).val(new_value);
          }
        }
      })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form>
    <input type="text" id="maskInput">
  </form>
```

Comment: Any way this can be done with in the Inputmask plugin to allow me to create a mask along with the asterisk hiding?

Comment: I'm afraid, I can't help with this. Never used this plugin.